# JQuery Cycle and JSON with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cycle

I found the jQuery Cycle plugin which is very interesting.

So, there is the following script that should return the images:

```
$(function() { 
// retrieve list of slides from server 
$.getJSON('slidelist.php', startSlideshow); 

function startSlideshow(slides) { 
    /* server returns an array of slides which looks like this: 
    [ 
        'images/beach2.jpg', 
        'images/beach3.jpg', 
        'images/beach4.jpg', 
        'images/beach5.jpg', 
        'images/beach6.jpg', 
        'images/beach7.jpg', 
        'images/beach8.jpg' 
    ] 
    */ 

    var totalSlideCount = 1 + slides.length; 

    var $slideshow = $('#slideshow'); 

    // markup contains only a single slide; before starting the slideshow we  
    // append one slide and prepend one slide (to account for prev/next behavior) 
    $slideshow.prepend('<img src="'+slides.pop()+'" />'); 
    $slideshow.append('<img src="'+slides.shift()+'" />'); 

    // start slideshow 
    $('#slideshow').cycle({ 
        fx: 'scrollHorz', 
        startingSlide: 1,  // start on the slide that was in the markup 
        timeout:  0, 
        speed:    500, 
        prev:    '#prev', 
        next:    '#next', 
        before:   onBefore 
    }); 


    function onBefore(curr, next, opts, fwd) { 
        // on Before arguments: 
        //  curr == DOM element for the slide that is currently being displayed 
        //  next == DOM element for the slide that is about to be displayed 
        //  opts == slideshow options 
        //  fwd  == true if cycling forward, false if cycling backward 

        // on the first pass, addSlide is undefined (plugin hasn't yet created the fn yet) 
        if (!opts.addSlide) 
            return; 

        // have we added all our slides? 
        if (opts.slideCount == totalSlideCount) 
            return; 

        // shift or pop from our slide array  
        var nextSlideSrc = fwd ? slides.shift() : slides.pop(); 

        // add our next slide 
        opts.addSlide('<img src="'+nextSlideSrc+'" />', fwd == false); 
    }; 
};
```

});

But, as I'm really bad in ajax, Can you tell me how can I use this

```
$.getJSON('slidelist.php', startSlideshow);
```

to return the images how can I receive theses images url?

Thank you very much,
regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. Is not about AJAX at all :)

The thing is that you receive an object inside of the function `startSlideshow`:

```
slides = [ 
    'images/beach2.jpg', 
    'images/beach3.jpg', 
    'images/beach4.jpg', 
    'images/beach5.jpg', 
    'images/beach6.jpg', 
    'images/beach7.jpg', 
    'images/beach8.jpg' 
];
```

Now you can iterate this object with a basic `for` loop:

```
for(var i=0, len = slides.length; i<len;i++){
        console.log(slides[i])
}
```

Right now, you have an image url on each step: `slides[i]`. You can append to `$('#slideshow')` and start playing around.