# Scroll slides automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got slideshow code below which works fine.  But I want slides to scroll automatically as at the moment with below code it works by clicking on Prev and Next button/link. Please can any body help that what I need in below code to make slides scroll whithout clicking Prev and Next button.

HTML

```
<div style="text-align:center"><a href="#"><span id="prev">Prev</span></a> <a href="#"><span id="next">Next</span></a></div>
<div id="slideshow">
  <img alt = "" src="images/beach1.jpg" />
</div>
```

Java/JQuery

```
$(function() { 
// retrieve list of slides from server 
$.getJSON('slidelist.php', startSlideshow);  

function startSlideshow(slides) { 
    /* server returns an array of slides which looks like this: 
    [ 
        'images/beach2.jpg', 
        'images/beach3.jpg', 
        'images/beach4.jpg', 
        'images/beach5.jpg', 
        'images/beach6.jpg', 
        'images/beach7.jpg', 
        'images/beach8.jpg' 
    ] 
    */ 

    var totalSlideCount = 1 + slides.length; 

    var $slideshow = $('#slideshow'); 

    // markup contains only a single slide; before starting the slideshow we  
    // append one slide and prepend one slide (to account for prev/next behavior) 
    $slideshow.prepend('<img src="'+slides.pop()+'" />'); 
    $slideshow.append('<img src="'+slides.shift()+'" />'); 

    // start slideshow 
    $('#slideshow').cycle({ 
        fx: 'scrollHorz', 
        startingSlide: 1,  // start on the slide that was in the markup 
        timeout:  0, 
        speed:    500, 
        prev:    '#prev', 
        next:    '#next', 
        before:   onBefore 
    }); 


    function onBefore(curr, next, opts, fwd) { 
        // on Before arguments: 
        //  curr == DOM element for the slide that is currently being displayed 
        //  next == DOM element for the slide that is about to be displayed 
        //  opts == slideshow options 
        //  fwd  == true if cycling forward, false if cycling backward 

        // on the first pass, addSlide is undefined (plugin hasn't yet created the fn yet) 
        if (!opts.addSlide) 
            return; 

        // have we added all our slides? 
        if (opts.slideCount == totalSlideCount) 
            return; 

        // shift or pop from our slide array  
        var nextSlideSrc = fwd ? slides.shift() : slides.pop(); 

        // add our next slide 
        opts.addSlide('<img src="'+nextSlideSrc+'" />', fwd == false); 
    }; 
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick (will work good if the shifting is in a cycle direction).

```
setInterval(function(){ $('#next').click(); )}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply so quick.  Please can you brief that where about should I put your code line in my code.

Comment: @KamranRasheed, Put it after all the functions.

Comment: Oh yes sorry.  It works but I have to click on next first.  Cant it just work when page is loaded as I want it to click free.

Comment: @KamranRasheed, Put it after `function startSlideshow(slides) {` function is closed.

Comment: @KamranRasheed, Helped you ?

Comment: Yes it works but I was hopping more for some kind of loop code instead of setInterval.  Someone has mentioned this in below link but I don’t know how to add this in my code.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340956/jquery-cycle-and-json-with-jquery)

Comment: @KamranRasheed, If it helped you, feel free to Accept the answer and UpVote.

Comment: sorry Orel its not what i am looking for.  I have mentioned above what i need which is loop system.  With your code it just moves next and even by clicking Prev button its still go to next.  Please see link above which i provided.